# Any way to remove 2 point polylines in bulk?

Tags: contour

QGIS:
I have successfully created contours from a DEM and subsequently cleaned them up using generalizer tools in the following order:
1.  Vertex reduction
2.  McMinimans distance algorithm.

The contours look great, but I am stuck with millions of dots that seem to be 2 point polylines with both vertex's in the same location, making them appear as single points.

These points are not selectable using the selection tool either which is maddening.

Can anyone help me with an idea of how to delete them in bulk or perhaps, how to not get them in the first place?

Comment: I would try the Select by expression tool from the View menu and select features which have $length=0. Then delete selected.